# Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and RoR. I am using the ruby gem [acts_as_votable](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_votable) to let users like and unlike posts. I added a "like" button to *all posts* on my *posts/index* page.

The button displays correctly and I am trying to make a button click like/unlike the post it is displayed on. When I click the button, to like a post, I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000002ba3b30>
  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

BTW: If you need anymore information, I will provide whatever I can.

## EDIT

Index page

```
- @post.each do |post|
    .box.panel.panel-default
      = link_to (image_tag post.image.url), post
      .post-actions
        = render "posts/actions"
      .panel-body
        %h2= link_to post.caption, post
```

Posts controller

```
      class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @post = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: "Success! Your new post has been created."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: "Success! You updated your post."
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def upvote
    @post.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :image)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put "admire", to: "posts#upvote"
    end
  end

  root "posts#index"
end
```

In terminal, I entered: rake routes. Here is the response:

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
             admire_post PUT    /posts/:id/admire(.:format)    posts#upvote
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                    root GET    /                              posts#index
```

Comment: Your params is passing in a collection of posts rather than a single post. Edit your question to include the form that populates your params hash.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Is this information sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your model, but let's test it like this:

1 - Open your rails console (type 'rails c' on the app dir), and write Post.first (Assuming you have posts), if that works the model should be fine.

2 - There must be something wrong with you params, change your find_post method to this:

```
  def find_post
    puts params
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Check the output, if you see anything different than a number (id) your passing it wrong on the view.

Comment: Step one worked properly. However, on step 2 I get the same error: `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#` : @post = Post.find(params[:id])

Comment: There, I edited the post to show what you actually have on params.
Probably @marczking answer solves your problem, but I wanted you to understand what's really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hello buddy I think It's a logic error You are putting

before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]

So the action 
 def index
    @post = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

where you are operating didn't find_post as you told only these actions to do so and even if :upvote is included the action index where all this is taking place isn't reading find_post.
Try adding :index to your list and let us see the reaction.

Hope this is helpful and enough explanation.

Comment: New error: Couldn't find Post with 'id'= `def find_post     @post = Post.find(params[:id])   end`

Comment: Ok then it's probably your routes to finding the routes make sure that the route to the Post is accurate to do so run 
bin$ rake routes 
It will list your routes and you will see the post route (remember we add path) 
and check if post leads to the post id if not then probably you need to change it to whatever in your rake routes to correspond.

Comment: Don't worry and don't give up most of the times it's just a small mistake like a space try seeing the logs and playing around and if you get other errors that's good. 
These mistakes are what really makes you learn how things happen in ruby because there are a lot of magic going on.

Comment: Please read the question, I added rake routes repsonce at the bottom of the question. I am new so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Ya  got it so try this

%= link_to admire_post_path(post) , method: :put

and it will probably work.

It may work better for you. But seriously play around A LOT and this playing around is what's going to give you the understanding of what ruby on rails is and does . A lot of magic going on in this language and trial and error is the only way to know what it does.

Comment: Hi did that work for you or something else did? I am really interested.

Answer (score 0):

Your `link_to` in your index-view passes an `ActiveRecord`-relation `post`.

```
= link_to (image_tag post.image.url), post
```

Change it so you pass the `post.id` as a parameter instead.

```
= link_to (image_tag post.image.url), post.id
```

*Edit*

You might even need to link it to something like `post_path(post)` or any equivalent you have set in your `routes.rb`. Then you don't need to set the `id`and just pass the whole `post`.